# ResizeEnd event on pressing Maximize button

Tags: vb.net, telerik

I am trying to show some hidden columns in a telerik RadGridView when the Form Window is Maximized.
I am aware of Resize Event but since Resize event is fired even before the Form is loaded, I am not using it.
I found that ResizeEnd suits my need but it is not reacting to Maximize button.
Is it possible to fire it with Maximize button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> since Resize event is fired even before the Form is loaded

Then add the handler in FormLoad instead of the designer

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Control.ResizeBegin, AddressOf controlResizeBegin
End Sub

Private Sub controlResizeBegin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```